# playing off previous runs?

Tags: rummikub

For Rummycube, after the 30 point meld can you build vertically off a run?

To illustrate, is this possible?

```
6 7 8 9
    8
    8
```

In addition if you had a gold, blue and a red 1, can you add to the same gold 1 going vertically a blue  and red 1?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "vertical."  Are you asking if you can build a set using a number that is already part of a run?

Comment: Yes, say a black run 3-4-5 on the board, can you add a red and blue 5 vertically. Or would you be able to play a black 3 and 4 off the 5?

Comment: Sorry it was unclear, I tried to post a picture but had trouble.

Answer (score 3):

You can not add tiles vertically like a crossword(number) puzzle. If a set has 4 or more tiles you can move one of them to create a new set. As long as the remaining sets are valid.

For example if 3,4,5,6 is on the table and you have two 6 (all three of different color) you can move the 6 and create a new set with your two 6 tiles. Getting 3,4,5 and 6,6,6.